# ActiveX Combobox value not setting to linkedcell on another sheet on workbook_open

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

We have created a workbook which use ActiveX objects and macros to perform multiple actions (calculations, changing values in cells, forcing mandatory fields before save, colour changes, lock and unlock, etc). There are 3 sheets:

**Lists** - where we set the values for comboboxes, run mandatory checks against cells and comboboxes, etc. this is VeryHidden to the user

**Form** - this is where the user will enter their data. it contains all of the ActiveX objects

**Import** - this is a formatted sheet which we can import to our database with expected formatting on values (i.e. "inches" instead of "in.H2O@60F", days converted to hours). this sheet is VeryHidden.

This workbook can be downloaded blank from our website and imported back into the database successfully.

What we want to do is download a pre-populated version where "Form" shows data from the database. To do this we are populating the Import sheet with the values (as they are already linked to the comboboxes we need to populate). i.e. ComboA on "Form" is linked to cell A4 on "Import".

We expected the comboboxes with linked cells to the update when we downloaded and opened the pre-populated workbook. When it did not we tried:

```
Sheets("Import").EnableCalculation = False
Sheets("Import").EnableCalculation = True
Application.Calculate
```

to force the row to "recalculate" and therefore trigger the linked cell to work as when we manually went into one of the linked cells and pressed enter (or F9) the associated combobox updated.

This was partially successful in that is populated around 1/3 of the comboboxes but not all of them. There does not seem to be an order or data type causing the issue (some Y/N update, others do not. comboboxes A-D will update, then E-G will not, then H will).

We tried Application.CalculateFull as well as:

- setting the linkedcells to Dirty
- only applying .Calculate to the range on the worksheet
- only applying .Calculate to the row on the worksheet (as it is all in one row)

We can manually force each combobox to populate with it's linked cell however given the number of comboboxes and the fact there will be more workbooks like this to build this is not an ideal solution.

We know it is hitting the `workbook_Open()` event as we put in some MsgBox items and the couple custom populations we do (converting degF to F then pushing to combobox) and that is working fine.

If we open the download, save it (skipping the mandatory fields before save), then reopen it everything populates/selects correctly (which is all the more frustrating).

Any thoughts on why the downloaded version is not acting as expected would be much appreciated.

Comment: Cripes, too long didn't read.  People like to scan a question quickly, see some code and mentally run the code in their head.  They can usually debug code in their head.  You have given no code.  Please post code.

Answer (score 0):

given the other posts I have seen and the follow up information requested I though more was better. there is a code snippet there - and we found a solution to the issue. needed to add `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` to the open event before the code provided above. thanks anyways